# How do I get back to the default Android Studio toolbar?

Tags: linux, ide-customization, android-studio-3.5.1

I recently updated my laptop to Ubuntu 18.04 and lost my Android Studio 3.5.1 settings including the toolbar, which now looks like this:

[image]

How do I get back to the default toolbar, which had a bunch of icons to the right of app drop-down menu (Select device drop-down menu, run button, Apply changes and restart, etc.)? Modifying the toolbar with right-click "Customize Menus and Toolbars..." doesn't work the way it did in earlier versions; there's no "Add after... button.

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio 3.5.3, after you right click in an empty area on the toolbar and select "Customize Menus and Toolbars...", you'll see the option to restore defaults at the top of the pop-up window.

Comment: Have you tried to restore the defaults through the settings dialogue (settings->Appearance & Behavior->Menus and toolbars)? Is it grayed out there as well?

Comment: Yes, it's disabled as well.